# styling xml returns same xml document, A way to get code to work

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xslt

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ICDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string SQL = "Select TUReportData from TUReport WHERE ConsumerID = @ConsumerID";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConsumerID", txtIDNumber.Text));

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        dt.TableName = "XMLData";
        dt.ToString();
        dt.WriteXml("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/TUWebServiceCaller/Log/temp.xml");

        // Getting file path    
        string strXSLTFile = Server.MapPath("styles/style.xslt");
        string strXMLFile = Server.MapPath("Log/temp.xml");

        // Creating XSLCompiled object    
        XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile);

        // Creating StringBuilder object to hold html data and creates TextWriter object to hold data from XslCompiled.Transform method    
        StringBuilder htmlOutput = new StringBuilder();
        TextWriter htmlWriter = new StringWriter(htmlOutput);

        // Creating XmlReader object to read XML content    
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile);

        // Call Transform() method to create html string and write in TextWriter object.    
        objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, null, htmlWriter);
        Results.InnerHtml  = htmlOutput.ToString();

        // Closing xmlreader object    
        reader.Close();
```

No errors when run but the XSLT doesn't seem to be styling the XML as it comes back in the same format its passed in. the whole xml should be reformatted and my own version of the whole page displayed with the nodes that i have specified in place

The XSLT
That is the XSLT example

```
<xsl:for-each select="AddressNA08">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="ConsumerNo"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="InformationDate"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Line1"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Line2"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Suburb"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="PostalCode"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="ProvinceCode"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Province"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="AddressPeriod"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="OwnerTenant"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="AddressChanged"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The XML

```
<AddressNA08>
    <ConsumerNo>645511310</ConsumerNo>
    <InformationDate>20090227</InformationDate>
    <Line1>8 HAAKBOS ST</Line1>
    <Line2 />
    <Suburb>ONVERWACHT</Suburb>
    <City>ELLISRAS</City>
    <PostalCode>0557</PostalCode>
    <ProvinceCode>
        NP
    </ProvinceCode>
    <Province>LIMPOPO</Province>
    <AddressPeriod>
        06
    </AddressPeriod>
    <OwnerTenant>O</OwnerTenant>
    <AddressChanged>N</AddressChanged>
</AddressNA08>
```

those are all the files that i am using

Comment: If this is an XSLT question, please show an example of the input XML document and show the `style.xslt` stylesheet.

Comment: is it possible to attach documents here

Comment: Xml example     <AddressNA08><ConsumerNo>645511310</ConsumerNo>     <InformationDate>20090227</InformationDate><Line1>8 HAAKBOS ST</Line1><Line2 /><Suburb>ONVERWACHT</Suburb><City>ELLISRAS</City><PostalCode>0557</PostalCode><ProvinceCode>NP</ProvinceCode><Province>LIMPOPO</Province><AddressPeriod>06</AddressPeriod><OwnerTenant>O</OwnerTenant><AddressChanged>N</AddressChanged></AddressNA08>

Comment: No, it's impossible to attach files here. And please do not link to off-site resources either. Cut down your sample XML and XSLT stylesheet to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit them into your question.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious... Did my answer help you to solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it does, but now what i have noticed is that when i use the retrieved xml and not the one i have been using, the tags < change to &lt; and > changes to &gt; and i need a work around this now

Comment: Please set the user's nick into your comment (e.g. `@Shnugo`). I did not get a notification and found this per incidence...

Comment: My code returns an `XmlDocument`. This *must* be a valid XML, otherwise it would throw an error... As I do not know how you continue after the transformation I suggest you the following: If my answer is the solution to **this** question, than please vote it up and mark it as accepted answer. And then add a new question with the new issue... I'll try to answer there quickly too.

Comment: @Shnugo please check the following link for follow up to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221037/writing-and-to-a-xml-file-instead-of-lt-and-gt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a method like this I transform xml via xslt to xhtml:

```
   public static XmlDocument TransformToHtml(XmlDocument XmlDoc, XmlDocument XSLT) {

        var bArr = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(XmlDoc.InnerXml);
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(bArr);
        System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument xDoc;
        XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xrs.CheckCharacters = false;
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(m, xrs)) {
            xDoc = new System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument(xr);
        }

        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();
        var ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        ws.CheckCharacters = false;
        ws.Indent = true;
        ws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(resultString, ws);
        var sets = new XsltSettings(true, true);

        string transformedXHTML = null;
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
        transform.Load(XSLT, sets, null);
        transform.Transform(xDoc, writer);
        transformedXHTML = resultString.ToString();
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(transformedXHTML);
        return doc;
    }
```

You call it like this (attention, shortened your xslt!):

```
        var xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml("<AddressNA08><ConsumerNo>645511310</ConsumerNo><InformationDate>20090227</InformationDate><Line1>8 HAAKBOS ST</Line1><Line2 />"
                   + "<Suburb>ONVERWACHT</Suburb><City>ELLISRAS</City><PostalCode>0557</PostalCode><ProvinceCode>NP</ProvinceCode><Province>LIMPOPO</Province>"
                   + "<AddressPeriod>06</AddressPeriod><OwnerTenant>O</OwnerTenant><AddressChanged>N</AddressChanged></AddressNA08>");

        var xslt = new XmlDocument();
        xslt.LoadXml("<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' version='1.0'>" +
                     "<xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml' standalone='no' omit-xml-declaration='no'/><xsl:template match='/'><xsl:for-each select='AddressNA08'>" +
                     "<tr><td><xsl:value-of select='ConsumerNo'/></td><td><xsl:value-of select='InformationDate'/></td><td><xsl:value-of select='Line1'/></td>" +
                     "<td><xsl:value-of select='Line2'/></td><td><xsl:value-of select='Suburb'/></td></tr></xsl:for-each></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>");
        var reslt = TransformToHtml(xml, xslt);
```

Comment: what would be the best way to post this to a new page when displaying the result?

Comment: @Tumelo, thx for upvote and acceptance! Here I don't know what you mean... If you want your XML to be converted to HTML through an XSL-Transformation, you do this as shown above. If your XSLT produces valid HTML (easy to test: Just paste the converted XML (use `doc.InnerXML`) into a new text file, call it `test.html` and open it with your browser), it should be not problem to display this on a "new page". Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

The XML document and stylesheet you show *do* produce an output that is different from the input document, so this is not the cause of error. I still want to add an answer because your XSLT stylesheet definitely needs improvement and I regard this as part of your problem.

Why write out every single element name and `td` element if you are going to output all of them anyway, even in the order they occurred in the input?

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AddressNA08">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**HTML Result**

```
<html>
   <tr>
      <td>645511310</td>
      <td>20090227</td>
      <td>8 HAAKBOS ST</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>ONVERWACHT</td>
      <td>ELLISRAS</td>
      <td>0557</td>
      <td>
         NP

      </td>
      <td>LIMPOPO</td>
      <td>
         06

      </td>
      <td>O</td>
      <td>N</td>
   </tr>
</html>
```

Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3k).

---

> i am going to omit some of the tags in the live project. or is the a way to select which to exclude when i use your way?

Yes, add an additional template where you list the names of elements that should not appear in the output. Here is an example:

```
<xsl:template match="City | PostalCode"/>
```

And [here is the updated online version](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3k/1).

Comment: You are right, that the xslt could be improved. And thank you for the link to the "XSLT-Fiddle", did not know that... +1 from my side for this information (even if your answer doesn't answer the question :-)   )

Comment: @Mathias Muller, i am going to omit some of the tags in the live project. or is the a way to select which to exclude when i use your way?

Comment: @Mathias, some guidance here [link](http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYix/3) No matter how i try calling the nodes they seem to not be working with the xsl please

Comment: @Tumelo That's because there are namespaces in your input document (that you did not show to us). We have a policy on Stackoverflow to not extend and change questions over and over. So, if you need help with this new document that you did not yet show to us, please ask a new question. As always for XSLT questions, in the new question you need to mention the following: a **complete** input document, your current XSLT code and the output you expect.